# C++ IS there a simplier way to see if a an address region is at least partially interesected with another?

Tags: c++, pointers, indexing, intersection

In c++, say I have a ring buffer with addresses. If the consumer is too slow, I want to drop the oldest data. So I have a block of indexes since the production amount may not be equal to the consumption amount. 
Where A = the head pointer, B = head pointer + new input data size, C = tail pointer - current read size, and D = the tail pointer. 
[A,B] [C,D]

What is the simplest way to check if these two intersect? Is it just explicitly writing all of the cases?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: As far as i can tell they intersect if `B >= C`.

Comment: B >= C is too weak of a condition.

Comment: I put the cases lke in where A <= C && B >= C,  A<= C && B >= D , A>= C &&  B <= D, etc.  I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @StephanieLoves, Edit your question to include your code.